# hyperledger error in configtxgen cant find file or directory

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

Reached the point where I've got the peers up and running for network and am now attempting to launch the channels.

- Trying to set up a Hyperledger network for channels using the I get the error:

  ```
  Loaded configuration: configtx.yaml
  main -> Error on outputBlock: could not create bootstrapper: 
  could not create channel group: 
  could not create orderer group: 
  cannot marshal metadata for orderer type etcdraft:
  cannot load client cert for consenter "IP":"Port": open /home/"User"/crw/rs/ord1-rs-crw-abc/docker-vol/tls/msp/tlscacerts/tlsca-cert.pem: no such file or directory.
  ```
- I log into the server through ssh and use cat to check the path it opens the certificate.
- The port is also open if I check it with telnet command it appears as open so I have no idea why it isn't able to find the file.
- Currently it crashes instead and giving the error I posted instead.

Answer (score 0):

Check configtx.yaml (may be share it here)

This path doesn't look good, I don't think docker can process those double-quotes on the path. Also, check for mappings on the container configuration so the path can be specified relative to the container.
/home/"User"/crw/rs/ord1-rs-crw-abc/docker-vol/tls/msp/tlscacerts/tlsca-cert.pem